# Pulling image from twitter in android

Tags: android, twitter, android-asynctask

I wrote a `TwitterAPI` to access the twitter apis.

```
public class TwitterAPI {

    private String twitterApiKey;
    private String twitterAPISecret;
    final static String TWITTER_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
    final static String TWITTER_STREAM_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=";

    public TwitterAPI(String twitterAPIKey, String twitterApiSecret) {
        this.twitterApiKey = twitterAPIKey;
        this.twitterAPISecret = twitterApiSecret;
    }

    public ArrayList<TwitterTweet> getTwitterTweets(String screenName) {
        ArrayList<TwitterTweet> twitterTweetArrayList = null;
        try {
            String twitterUrlApiKey = URLEncoder.encode(twitterApiKey, "UTF-8");
            String twitterUrlApiSecret = URLEncoder.encode(twitterAPISecret, "UTF-8");
            String twitterKeySecret = twitterUrlApiKey + ":" + twitterUrlApiSecret;
            String twitterKeyBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(twitterKeySecret.getBytes(),
                    Base64.NO_WRAP);
            TwitterAuthToken twitterAuthToken = getTwitterAuthToken(twitterKeyBase64);
            twitterTweetArrayList = getTwitterTweets(screenName, twitterAuthToken);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | IllegalStateException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return twitterTweetArrayList;
    }

    public ArrayList<TwitterTweet> getTwitterTweets(String screenName,
                                                    TwitterAuthToken twitterAuthToken) {
        ArrayList<TwitterTweet> twitterTweetArrayList = null;
        if (twitterAuthToken != null && twitterAuthToken.token_type.equals("bearer")) {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(TWITTER_STREAM_URL + screenName);
            httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "
                    +twitterAuthToken.access_token);
            httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            HttpUtil httpUtil = new HttpUtil();
            String twitterTweets = httpUtil.getHttpResponse(httpGet);
            twitterTweetArrayList = convertJsonToTwitterTweet(twitterTweets);
        }
        return twitterTweetArrayList;
    }

    public TwitterAuthToken getTwitterAuthToken(String twitterKeyBase64)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(TWITTER_TOKEN_URL);
        httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + twitterKeyBase64);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("grant_type=client_credentials"));
        HttpUtil httpUtil = new HttpUtil();
        String twitterJsonResponse = httpUtil.getHttpResponse(httpPost);
        return convertJsonToTwitterAuthToken(twitterJsonResponse);
    }

    private TwitterAuthToken convertJsonToTwitterAuthToken(String jsonAuth) {
        TwitterAuthToken twitterAuthToken = null;
        if (jsonAuth != null && jsonAuth.length() > 0) {
            try {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                twitterAuthToken = gson.fromJson(jsonAuth, TwitterAuthToken.class);
            } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return twitterAuthToken;
    }

    private ArrayList<TwitterTweet> convertJsonToTwitterTweet(String twitterTweets) {
        ArrayList<TwitterTweet> twitterTweetArrayList = null;
        if (twitterTweets != null && twitterTweets.length() > 0) {
            try {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                twitterTweetArrayList = gson.fromJson(twitterTweets,
                        new TypeToken<ArrayList<TwitterTweet>>() {
                }.getType());
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return twitterTweetArrayList;
    }

    private static class TwitterAuthToken {
        String token_type;
        String access_token;
    }

}
```

Then I used that in `async` as follows

```
public class TwitterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, ArrayList<TwitterTweet>> {

    ListActivity callerActivity;

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<TwitterTweet> doInBackground(Object... params) {
        ArrayList<TwitterTweet> twitterTweets = null;
        callerActivity = (ListActivity) params[1];
        if (params.length > 0) {
            TwitterAPI twitterAPI = new TwitterAPI(TWITTER_API_KEY, TWITTER_API_SECRET);
            twitterTweets = twitterAPI.getTwitterTweets(params[0].toString());
        }
        return twitterTweets;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<TwitterTweet> twitterTweets) {
        ArrayAdapter<TwitterTweet> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(callerActivity,
                R.layout.activity_twitter_view, R.id.listTextView, twitterTweets);
        callerActivity.setListAdapter(adapter);
        ListView lv = callerActivity.getListView();
        lv.setDividerHeight(0);
        //lv.setDivider(this.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
        lv.setBackgroundColor(callerActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_white));
    }
}
```

This pulls data as shown in this image
[image: twitter]
But this doesn't pull the images which are associated with tweets that are being pulled. How can I modify twitter API to get images?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a parameter to the [statuses user timeline API service](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline) to avoid truncating the tweets. This will retrieve the full tweet, not only text but also images.

The parameter is `tweet_mode=extended`.

So, I suggest you to modify your `TWITTER_STREAM_URL` constant to the following:

```java
final static String TWITTER_STREAM_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?tweet_mode=extended&screen_name=";
```

Now, you'll see that the response will include an array of tweets. For each tweet you'll find an `entities` field that contains a `media` field. This one contains an array of media items. Each media item has a `type`, if this has a value of `photo`, then you can obtain the image using either of the following fields: `media_url` or `media_url_https`.

To give an example, by performing a GET request to [my user timeline](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?tweet_mode=extended&screen_name=fernandospr) (You need to use your Bearer Token), you'll find the following tweet:

```json
{
    "id": 1264252718828437505,
    "id_str": "1264252718828437505",
    "full_text": "Just noticed that AS won't warn about the specific hardcoded string \"Hello World!\" in activity_main.xml (or any other xml).\nI guess they had to hardcode an if statement to not warn about it.  ",
    "truncated": false,
    "entities": {
        "media": [
            {
                "id": 1264251325023498240,
                "id_str": "1264251325023498240",
                "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/EYuF4b7XsAAOGGi.jpg",
                "media_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EYuF4b7XsAAOGGi.jpg",
                "type": "photo",
...
```

You didn't post your `TwitterTweet` class but you'll also need to modify it to include these fields, something like this:

```java
public class TwitterTweet {
    ...
    Entities entities;
}

public class Entities {
    List<Media> media;
}

public class Media {
    String mediaUrl;
    String type;
}
```

You can find more info on the Tweet, Entities and Media objects, [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/overview/intro-to-tweet-json).